# webservices smart device c#

Tags: c#, web-services

Hello guys I really have a big problem. Everytime I try to consume a webservice from an emulator, I always receive the message "Unable to connect to remote server". I already tried installing mobile device center and cradle the emulator. I literally tried doing all the stuff I see on the internet but no success. Hope you have new suggesion. Thanks in advance! By the way even my professor cant fix this problem LOL

Comment: THe error means what it says, it can't connect to the web service endpoint you have specified. How are you consuming the web service? Is it a web reference, what happens if you try to access the web service via a browser?

Comment: What device? What platform? Windows Phone7? Windows Mobile? How are you trying to consume a webservice? Provide a code of consumption attempt to analyze.

Comment: Hi this is larry! I added it as a web reference. I can access it via the pocket pc 5.0 IE but i cant invoke it.

Comment: Hi this is larry! This is my code: localhost.Service1 ws = localhost.Service1(); string s = ws.HelloWorld();

Comment: Hi this is larry! To be honest Im actually doing this for weeks now. Im really disappointed that my professor cant really help us out on this. I would really appreciate it if somebody would spend time helping me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi this is larry! Im using USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator on MSVS08

Answer (score 0):

Ensure, that you're connecting to the `My Work` networks in control panel, not the `My ISP` and craddle the emulator with the emulator device manager (you'll find it under `Tools` in Visual Studio 2008). Verify, that you can access your webservice from the mobile version of IE. I'm currently not at work, so I can't give you a more detailed description.